# How can I determine the largest integer value in a string?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here is what I have:

```
largest_int=None

def largest_digit(string_one):
    for ch in string_one:
        if not string_one.isdigit():
            largest_int=None
        elif ch in string_one.isdigit():
            largest_int=ch>ch
            print (largest_int)

largest_digit('Hello 1 2 3 5 4')
```

I'm trying to tell python to pull the integers from a string and print the largest one.  My code isn't working however, and I would appreciate any help with fixing it without using something like import re.

Comment: `max(int(n) for n in 'Hello 1 2 3 5 4'.split() if n.isdigit()) `

Comment: I suppose it is ambiguous what is wanted here. Support for negatives? More than 1 digit? Separated by what?

Answer (score 2):

If you create a generator that yields only the digits in the string, you will be able to use `max`.

```
def largest_digit(string_one):
    return max(int(ch) for ch in string_one.split() if ch.isdigit())
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'filter' combined with a lambda expression. I don't know if it's the better solution, but I will put here to show another way to solve the problem.

```
def largest_digit(string_one):
    return max(filter(lambda x: int(x) if x.isdigit() else 0, string_one.split()))
```

Comment: Interesting example of [`filter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) and [`lambda`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#lambda) but 
`Note that filter(function, iterable) is equivalent to the generator expression (item for item in iterable if function(item)) if function is not None...`
And you don't need the lambda -> `max( filter(str.isdigit, string_one.split()) )` so this is equivalent to the other generator answers.

Answer (score -1):

```
def largest_digit(string_one):
    tmp=[]
    for e in string_one.split():
        try:
            tmp.append( int(e) )
        except:
            pass
    print( max( tmp ) )

largest_digit('Hello 1 2 3 5 4')
```